# Net::SSH fails to connect

Tags: ruby, macos, net-ssh

I've written a ruby script to do some work on a remote host. Running it from a Mac with 10.6. The IP works fine with a manual ssh -l devacct 10.10.10.10, but as you can see it fails in the script.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start("10.10.10.10", "devacct", :password => "password1") do |ssh|
end
```

Fails horribly with:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:65:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

Any ideas? :)

Kind Regards

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes. (scuttles off to try logging in to 10.10.10.10. :-)

Comment: @Tin Man - I changed the IP to protect our top secret servers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly this exception is thrown if the hostname can't be resolved. Make sure the ip adress you try to connect to is correct and reachable.

Comment: The IP is real and it works when I do a manual ssh. thanks for your answer

Comment: OK you were right, it failed deeper inside the script on another ssh.start :)